# Android 5.0 License Check always returning NOT_LICENSED

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-lvl

I've been using LVL for years without issue. I have my account setup so that I am a valid license tester, and thus, I should be able to configure the response through the develop console.  I have recently upgraded my app to be Android 5.0 compliant (i.e. targetSDK is now API level 21).  I am aware that I must use explicit intents when binding to a service (like LVL) on API level 21 and have made the appropriate changes (in fact, before I made this change, I could not even bind to the LVL service, and now I can, so I know I made that change properly).  The problem is, when I run my app on a Lollipop device (Nexus 5 with factory image) I always get NOT_LICENSED from the server,  If I run the same app on a KitKat device, I get he response i have configured through the develop console.  So this appears to be a Lollipop specific issue.  Has anyone else encountered this, and if so, how did you solve it.

Comment: do you have an example of how you change it to use explicit intents, as the sample license app still uses implicit intents

Comment: Yes - you want: 
`Intent intent = new Intent(ILicensingService.class.getName());`
`intent.setPackage("com.android.vending");`
`boolean bindResult = mContext.bindService(
                     intent,
                        this,  // ServiceConnection.
                        Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);`

Comment: thanks Rob, someone gave the answer in a Question I created http://stackoverflow.com/q/27209510/1527440, that said having you had problems with license checker on the Lollipop emulator, or are using a physical device, thanks

Comment: Arg.  Can't delete a comment.  See my solution.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else runs into this, the issue cleared itself up after about 48 hours. I did not make any changes to my app, nor did I change anything with my google play developer account configuration.  I just walked away from the problem for a few days, and when I came back, it worked as expected.  So I suspect the issue was on Google's end.

Comment: If you answered this question. Please mark correct.

Answer (score 1):

I've been experiencing this too.  Some of my users are always getting NOT_LICENSED even when everything is correct.  It appears to be primarily users that have more than one device.  The only solution I have found so far is a factory reset (yuck).  If I find something better, I'll post it here.

This is an issue separate from fact that LVL has been broken for months in Lollipop.  For that, my solution that is more complicated, but doesn't require hard coding the package name.

```
                final Intent intent =  new Intent(
                        new String(
                                Base64.decode("Y29tLmFuZHJvaWQudmVuZGluZy5saWNlbnNpbmcuSUxpY2Vuc2luZ1NlcnZpY2U=")));
                final ResolveInfo resolveInfo = mContext.getPackageManager().resolveService(intent, 0);
                final ServiceInfo serviceInfo = resolveInfo.serviceInfo;
                final ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(serviceInfo.packageName, serviceInfo.name);
                intent.setComponent(componentName);
                boolean bindResult = mContext
                        .bindService(
                               intent,
                                this, // ServiceConnection.
                                Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```