# Lollipop 5.0 Sample License Checker App crashes on Emulator (AVD)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-5.0-lollipop, android-lvl

When running the the sample license check app provided by Google in sdk/extras/google/play_licensing it crashes on the Emulator(AVD) running Lollipop (5.0) (I don't have a phone running 5.0). It works fine on Phone running Kitkat.

On 4.4 Kitkat it gives a warning the

```
Implicit intents with startService are not safe: Intent { act=com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService } 

android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService:538 com.google.android.vending.licensing.LicenseChecker.checkAccess:150 LicActivity.doCheck:126
```

I am not sure 5.0 they have moved it from a warning to full blown error.

I don't know how to convert the implicit intent call to an explicit one. 
It's being called in the LicenceChecker class

```
   boolean bindResult = mContext
                            .bindService(
                                    new Intent(
                                            new String(
                                               Base64.decode("HEX_TEXT"))),
                                    this, // ServiceConnection.
                                    Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

BASE 64 decodes into com.android.vending.licensing.ILicensingService

I just receive an error message **Unfortunately, licence checker has stopped.** in a dialog box.

It is showing this message in logcat

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.android.vending.VendingApplication: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:

 Didn't find class "com.android.vending.VendingApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/app/LicenseChecker/LicenseChecker.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

It's been reported a while back but still no solution

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61680

Comment: And your logcat says what?

Comment: I have added that after following ianhanniballake way to remove the warning, logcat message with a bug reported to Google year ago

Answer (score 8):

Adding

```
intent.setPackage("com.android.vending");
```

to your `Intent` ensures that it is an explicit intent as required by Android 5.0.

Comment: thanks that solved the warning but the app still crashes on Lollipop, I have added more details above

Comment: Make sure you are using the Google APIs emulator as per the [emulator setup instructions](http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/setting-up.html#runtime-emulator)

Comment: it is using Google APIs API Level 21, all the other emulators (4.2) work fine

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(
     new String(Base64.decode("Y29tLmFuZHJvaWQudmVuZGluZy5saWNlbnNpbmcuSUxpY2Vuc2luZ1NlcnZpY2U=")));
     serviceIntent.setPackage("com.android.vending");

     boolean bindResult = mContext
             .bindService(
               serviceIntent,
               this, // ServiceConnection.
               Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

Comment: that's the same answer ianhanniballake gave above

Comment: that's exactly the same code I used after following ianhanniballake suggestion